# is it posible to specify two rotation points in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

I´m struggling to simulate wobbling effects. Basically I have a rectangle and I have to twist one edge in one direction (clockwise), while simulaneously twisting the parallel edge in the opposite direction (counterclockwise). I have to use up arrow key to speed the wobbling effect and the down arrow key to slow the wobbling effect.

Comment: You can't do this with one affine transformation. Either use an appropriate shader or calculate the rectangle points on the CPU.

Comment: do you have a project in github? I want to start developing OpenGL and it would be great to work with someone. If not you could just point me to a book you are using... please?

Comment: honestly, I´m new too, about the book i´m using the Redbook